# Can't match regular expression

Tags: regex

I have a file with lots of repeated blocks like this

```
<li>
<span>תמונה מאירוע</span>
<a href="images/gallerys/events/big/109.jpg"
title="תמונה מאירוע"><img
src="images/gallerys/events/thumbnails/109.jpg" alt="cars" />
</a>
</li>
```

I want to find pairs of texts of image url and thumb url 
My pattern is:

```
href='(.*)'(.*)title(.*)src='(.*?)'
```

The problem is returned to me the text from the first href to the last src

Comment: what language do you use?

Comment: Make your capturing groups non-greedy: `(.*)` -> `(.*?)`. Just parse the HTML. It'll be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript implementation

```
var m,
    pairs = [],
    rex = /<li>[\s\S]*?<a href="([^"]+)"[\s\S]+?<img\s+src="([^"]+)"/g,
    str = '<li>\n' +
          '<span>תמונה מאירוע</span>\n' +
          '<a href="images/gallerys/events/big/109.jpg"\n' +
          'title="תמונה מאירוע"><img\n' +
          'src="images/gallerys/events/thumbnails/109.jpg" alt="cars" />\n' +
          '</a>\n' +
          '</li>';

while ( m = rex.exec( str ) ) {
    pairs.push( [ m[1], m[2] ] );
}

console.log( pairs );
```

Assumes no quotes within urls.

Using a proper HTML parser would be more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `'` in your example. The title attribute is in this case in a new line, so you'll never be able to match that properly. These are just a couple of examples but there are many more to deal with, and it's impossible to do it right with pure regexp.

Whatever language you use (except perhaps the bash/sed/awk... family) it will support parsing the HTML into a DOM tree, and with that you can easily find the needed nodes.

*Note: as others pointed out, one of the problems is that `.*` is greedy, meaning it will eat us much characters as possible. If you're really stubborn, you can solve this with a non-greedy version `.*?` or charset matches like `[^"']*`.*

Comment: It is possible that SO wrapped the string, however, I think there is a multi-line flag for most regex engines? /m?